# How to avoid re-inserting data (duplicates) into SQL Server table while re-running SSIS package that loads data?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, duplicates, etl, sql-server-data-tools

I have created a package is SSIS. It's working fine for first time insertion. When I am running the package through SQL Server agent jobs, I am getting duplicates inserted when the scheduled job is inserting data.

I don't have any idea about how to stop inserting multiple duplicate records.

I am expecting to remove duplicates insertion while running deployed package through SQL Server Jobs

[image]

Answer (score 4):

There are 2 approaches to do that:

**(1) using SQL Command**

*This option can be used if source and destination are on the same server*

Since you are using ADO.NET source you can change the Data Access mode to *SQL Command* and select only data that not exists in the destination:

```
SELECT *
FROM SourceTable
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
                SELECT 1
                FROM DestinationTable
                WHERE SourceTable.ID = DestinationColumn.ID)
```

**(2) using Lookup Transformation**

You can use a Lookup transformation to get the non-matching rows between Source and destination and ignore duplicates:

- [UNDERSTAND SSIS LOOKUP TRANSFORMATION WITH AN EXAMPLE STEP BY STEP](http://www.learnmsbitutorials.net/ssis-lookup-transformation-example.php)
- [SSIS - only insert rows that do not exists](http://jahaines.blogspot.com/2009/09/ssis-only-inserting-rows-that-do-not.html)
- [SSIS import data or insert data if no match](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/92041/ssis-import-data-or-insert-data-if-no-match)
- [Implementing Lookup Logic in SQL Server Integration Services](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/ssis/implementing-lookup-logic-in-sql-server-integration-services/)

Answer (score -1):

In order to remove duplicates use SQL Task with the following query (assuming that you are not extracting million of rows and you want to remove duplicates on the extracted data, not destination) :

```
with cte as (

select field1,field2, row_number() over(partition by allfieldsfromPK order by allfieldsfromPK) as rownum)
delete from cte where rownum > 1
```

Then use a Data Flow Task and insert clean data into destination table.

In case you just want to not insert duplicates , a very good option is to use MERGE statement, a more performant alternative.

Comment: Delete command is not recommended at all, why deleting duplicates when you can avoid inserting them??!! In addition how Delete commands will perform in case of huge volume of data stored in tables??